# Call native function from file without /clr

Tags: c++, clr

I have a C++ Windows Forms Project in Visual Studio but I need some functions that cannot be compiled using the `Common Language Runtime Support /clr`

So I added a new cpp file with native code and set to compile it without /clr.

Assume that I have a function called `getNativeData()` which returns a `std::string`, how can I call this function from my Windows Forms header file?

Comment: It is completely unclear why this is a problem.  Post code, be explicit about what goes wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's apparently some kind of bug in Visual Studio, i excluded the files from the project and added them again. This solved it.